# Align 3 lines in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a 3 signature line that needs to be aligned. The problems are:

1. I want the names(admin1, admin2, admin3) of each should be at the center of the signature line.
2. the 3 signature lines should be on the most left, center, and most right of the page.

```css
.signature {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.signature_div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="signature_div">
  <div class="Column">
    <input type="text" class="signature" /><br /> Admin1
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <input type="text" class="signature" /><br /> Admin2
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <input type="text" class="signature" /><br /> Admin3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` on the parent to space the signatures on the page and then use `text-align: center;` on a wrapper element around each signature.

```css
.signature {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.signature_div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.signature-wrapper {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="signature_div">
  <div class="Column">
    <label class="signature-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="signature" /><br />
      Admin1
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <label class="signature-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="signature" /><br />
      Admin2
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <label class="signature-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="signature" /><br />
      Admin3
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn beat me :P

Comment: @itodd. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for content alignment. It is incredibly useful.

```css
.signature {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.signature_div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack:justify;
      -ms-flex-pack:justify;
          justify-content:space-between;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Column {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="signature_div">
  <div class="Column">
    <input type="text" class="signature" /><br /> Admin1
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <input type="text" class="signature" /><br /> Admin2
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <input type="text" class="signature" /><br /> Admin3
  </div>
</div>
```